# Improving performance of python sha1 hash bruteforcer

Tags: python, performance, hash, sha1, brute-force

I'm making my custom hash bruteforcer with usage of sha1 and base64 in python. However, it works very slow. I read about three modules I can use: threading, concurrent.future and multiprocessing. Can someone tell the difference between these, which I should use and why the others are not as good as the chosen one? Also, please tell me what can I do to speed this code up. Here's the code:

```
import time
import hashlib
import itertools

charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
good = "" #here I supply the hash

start = time.time()

def encrypt(password):
    hsah = hashlib.sha1(password).digest()
    hsah = hsah.encode("base64")[:-1] + "" #here I have something like 'salt' which is needed
    hsah = hashlib.sha1(hsah).hexdigest()
    if hsah == good:
        print "password found!", password
        end = time.time()
        roz = end - start
        print roz
        exit()

passwords = itertools.product(charset, repeat=7)

for password in passwords:
    encrypt("".join(password))
```

Comment: *"However, it works very slow"* - As it should :-)

Comment: to be clearer, a major purpose of a cryptographic hash like sha1 is that it is not feasible to brute-force with proper use, so no matter how quickly you could make attempts with even cutting-edge hardware, it will never be sufficiently fast to successfully discover the original value within a human lifetime - that said, it does seem like an exciting exercise and you may also be interested in asyncio

Comment: @ti7 It's just 78 billion possibilities, that shouldn't take a lifetime.

Comment: certainly an afternoon's activity for some! .. still, this is due to their improper use (exactly 7-char source value?..) just adding `' '` to their charset is another 16 billion possibilities, to say nothing of adding a large and unknown salt

Comment: @ti7 Adding what to their charset? (I guess your comment isn't formatted like you intended.)

Comment: Doing such a computation in Python is not efficient (and more generally any brute-force algorithm). Consider using languages like C, C++, D, Rust, etc. to generate a fast binary executing a parallel implementation. The library implementation matters a lot. Some processors (like recent Intel ones) have dedicated low-level SIMD instructions to compute SHA-1 very quickly. The cost of allocating 1 temporary Python object is much higher than computing a SHA-1 hash instruction, so any Python implementation cannot compete with a low-level optimized code.